# Storing Json string In database return NULL in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

[image: Here is My Json Request]

**When insert this code into my database the slide column will inserted as Null**

How Can Insert My slide value into my database..
slide column is Json type

Comment: Did you `cast` that in you model? like `$casts = ['slide' => 'json']` ?

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan yes
 `public function setSlidesAttribute($value)
    {
        $this->attributes['slides'] = json_encode($value);
    }`
    `public function getSlidesAttribute($value)
    {
        return json_decode($value);
    }`
this is the code

Comment: I think you don't need it to do manual, please use my example, and tell me the result

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan I Have tried `protected $casts = [
        'slides' => 'json',
    ];`
BUT still The Inserting value is NULL

Comment: your input name is `slide` but you used `slides`, have you checked the database column name also to be `slide`?

Comment: So can you mark my answer as usefull?

Comment: @MiqayelSrapionyan Sure Why Not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Laravel attributes casting in model like this.

```
protected $casts = [
    'slide' => 'json'
];
```

[Docs.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting)